# sharing file across multiple EC2 instances

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have php and apache installed on an EC2 instance. When I Terminate or I shut down the instance I lose all the files on that instance. The only way to prevent that is to use EBS volume, but I don't Want to do that. What I want to do is to keep my php file in a certain place such that when traffic is routed to a certain EC2 instance, the instance have access to these php file. Basically I want the same php files to be shared across multiple EC2 instances. What is the the best way to do it. Is Amazon s3 the solution for that ?

Comment: EBS is exactly what you should be using, that's its purpose.

Comment: @smith can I use single volume of EBS on multiple instances

Comment: typo "EFS" isdesigned for this

Comment: @smith dont you lose your data on EFS when you stop the instance

Comment: no its completely independent, you can use it with out a instance

Comment: When the EC2 instances are launched from scratch, you can download the PHP files from a private S3 bucket and then start up PHP. That's a (very) basic way of bootstrapping your compute instances.

Comment: Note: EFS is not available in all regions.